# How do bomb calorimeters ignite the food inside the chamber and control the combustion?

Tags: thermodynamics

How do bomb calorimeters ignite the food inside the chamber, especially when it is a very moist food? Do they dry out the food before burning? Do they change the internal pressure of the burn chamber? Do they use super hot heating elements?

How do they control the rate of combustion of highly energetic foods (like chocolate cake), so they don't accidentally destroy the calorimeter and surrounding equipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "control" the rate of combustion inside a bomb calorimeter.  Given that you know the approximate heat content of the sample (e.g., 4 cal/g for a carbohydrate), you can use an appropriately small sample size such that the heat release does not cause the pressure in the calorimeter to exceed design specifications.  Once this sample is loaded into the calorimeter, it is filled with pure oxygen and sealed.  The sample is ignited with a spark or hot wire (electronic ignition), and the pure oxygen causes the sample to immediately burn. 
 Assuming that the chemical composition of the sample is known (a good assumption), the temperature rise and pressure rise inside the calorimeter can be predicted.

This is pure speculation on my part, but I assume that before experimenters had adequate experience with bomb calorimeters, they caused a few to blow apart because they used too big of a sample, leading to the current name of the device.